# Yii 1 Framework / PHP: How to change the include path?

Tags: php, yii

I have a application which is running on the Yii 1 Framework.

This is how the project structure looks like:

```
\app
   \config
   \models
   \views
   ... and a lot more
\css
\js
\img
\.. and some more stuff
index.php
```

To improve the security, I want to make sure, that application (php) files or other stuff is in the root directory.

I want to have following structure:

```
\app
    \config
    \models
    \views
    ... and a lot more
\htdocs [ROOT]
    \css
    \js
    \img
    index.php
```

After changing the structure, I get errors as expected. I already changed the path in /htdocs/index.php, but there are more:

```
No such file or directory in [...]\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php on line 133
```

Is there an easy way to fix all the paths, without changing 1 million paths in the framework?

Thank you very much!

Comment: So, as I understand problem in connection yii? Is it right? Where is store files of framework?(physical path). And show your index.php please.

Comment: Have a look here and report back http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/116/moving-project-code-outside-of-webroot-plus-multiple-project-support/

Answer (score 0):

How I understand, you move you front controller (`index.php`) to your ROOT doc? If you will look into `index.php` file you will se line of code like this:

```
$yii = dirname(__FILE__) . '...some/directories/yiisoft/yii/framework/yii.php';
```

Then it file requires and creating Application, you need to change it path to proper.